# What effect does the ruby regular expression option `n` have?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm reading this line in ruby [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_5/lib/net/http/response.rb#L41):

```
m = /\AHTTP(?:\/(\d+\.\d+))?\s+(\d\d\d)(?:\s+(.*))?\z/in.match(str) or
```

I don't see the `n` option described in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options). What does it do? To test properly, I'd need an HTTP server that will return 1xx responses. So I couldn't yet do it. But it looks like a bug. A `sock.readline` will return something like `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"`, and this doesn't match the RE. If the option was `m`, it would have made more sense. I'm wondering whether this is some untested code path and somebody used `n` vs `m`. Why does `n` not fail if this was the case? I tried other random letters, and they fail. See some simple tests:

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" =~ /\AHTTP(?:\/(\d+\.\d+))?\s+(\d\d\d)(?:\s+(.*))?\z/im
#=> 0
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" =~ /\AHTTP(?:\/(\d+\.\d+))?\s+(\d\d\d)(?:\s+(.*))?\z/in
#=> nil
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" =~ /\AHTTP(?:\/(\d+\.\d+))?\s+(\d\d\d)(?:\s+(.*))?\z/iz
#=> SyntaxError: (eval):2: unknown regexp option - z
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scroll down a bit in the docs, you'll find: `/pat/n - ASCII-8BIT`

This overrules the current source encoding (default UTF-8)

Comment: hmm, embarrassed for missing this :/, Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`//n` means `NOENCODING`. From the Ruby tests:

```
def test_has_NOENCODING
  assert Regexp::NOENCODING
  re = //n
  assert_equal Regexp::NOENCODING, re.options
end
```

So it must mean to disregard all multiple byte character sequences and treat everything as raw bytes.